# Tool to check duplication of classes in css

Tags: css

Some of dovelopers working here rose some duplication of classes in css, have some tool to do a scanner and find these duplicates?

Thanks.

Comment: http://rbtech.github.io/css-purge

Answer (score 0):

Try the firefox addon, great debugging tools for developers

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-usage/

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a tool a little while back that does this: https://github.com/rbtech/css-purge